# Depth camera : How can I determine the origin of reference for the depth camera?

Tags: image, 3d, camera, artificial-intelligence, depth

While using the Helios2+ Time of Flight (ToF) IP67 3D Camera fixed on a collaborative robot Doosan, my objective is to obtain the reference of the depth camera and subsequently transform it to the robot's reference frame. This transformation will enable me to provide the robot with specific points or coordinates as input for its navigation. Do you have any idea how to do it.

Here is an illustration of the camera capture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oynVu.png)